# Error: QML Column: Cannot specify top, bottom, verticalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors for items inside Column

Tags: qt, qml

```
file:///home/biergaizi/WeCase.commit/src//ui/SmileyDelegate.qml:6:5: 
QML Column: Cannot specify top, bottom, verticalCenter, fill or centerIn 
anchors for items inside Column
```

Why I got that? I tried to comment each line without find answer.
I do not have any idea with it.

SmileyView.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300; height: 200


    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 36; cellHeight: 40

        model: SmileyModel
        delegate: SmileyDelegate {}
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
        focus: true
    }
}
```

SmileyDelegate.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    width: grid.cellWidth; height: grid.cellHeight

    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Image { source: path; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
        Text { text: name; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                highlight: color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 
                grid.currentIndex = index 
            }
            onDoubleClicked: {
                parentWindow.returnSmileyName('[' + name + ']')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Column is trying to anchor your MouseArea to next to the Image and the Text, but the MouseArea  specifies its anchor to fill its parent. Those two things are contradictory, and hence why you get the error.

You'll probably find it works as you expect if you move the MouseArea out of Column and into the base Item for SmileyDelegate.